# Change the src of an iFrame using select tag (without javascript)

Tags: html, iframe

Currently, what I have looks something like the following...

```html
<a href="./option1.pdf" target="frame">option 1</a>
<a href="./option2.pdf" target="frame">option 2</a>

<iframe name="frame"></iframe>
```

However, I'd like to use the selected option of a `<select>` tag to change the source of my frame instead.
Is this possible to do without using javacript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the select element inside a form, set the target of the form to the frame, add a submit button, and then submit it.

Then you’ll need to map the URLs generated (the form’s action with a query string containing the name and value of the select element) to your PDFs on the server.